# Why are Square Integrable Functions important in Statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, definition, integral, decomposition

I'm reading a paper by Giles Hooker on [Functional Decomposition](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=functional%20anova%20hooker&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&t=1675974995231&u=%23p%3DWWTv4YgjCCkJ) through the use of Functional ANOVA.

In the paper he defines a function:

$$ F(x) : \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$

and explicitly states that we must let $F(x)$ be square integrable.

I've read before that square integrable functions are important in statistics but I can't find any sources that explain why.

What are the uses of square integrable functions? Why do we care about them in statistics?

Comment: This is just a matter of terminology: square-integrable is equivalent to having a finite variance.  Without that, it becomes difficult to say much about estimators, asymptotic behavior of statistics, and more; and it's impossible to do ANOVA (whose very name is an acronym for variance decompositions).

Comment: Thank you! So what does ANOVA actually stand for then? Additive, ?, ?, Variance, ?. Also, if it's just a way of saying "Has finite variance", why did the author write square integrable? Is there a reason you'd do one over the other?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance